# Turn on the location using React Native

Tags: react-native, location

I would like to know if it is possible to turn on the location using React Native without the library. I just need to turn on the location. I searched but I just found about librarys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually in older version of react native it offers [Geolocation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/geolocation.html) to enable and get location.

In newer version they separate it from react native package in order to decrease the size of react native package and shift to

[@react-native-community/geolocation](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-geolocation)